# Find $near location wrong result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a business collection, with branch as nested document, location is define as `type: [Number]` in mongoose:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5466f87edb96504c30e910db"),
    "name" : "Microsoft",
    "description" : "Microsoft Redmond",
    "branch" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Redmond",
            "location" : [ 
                -122.130137,
                47.644702
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5466f87edb96504c30e910dd")
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Seattle",
            "location" : [ 
                -122.326241, 
                47.599146
            ],
            "_id" : ObjectId("5466f87edb96504c30e910dc")
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now I try to search for nearest to my current location:

```
db.business.find(
   { "branch.location": { $near: [-122.326412, 47.623022], $maxDistance: 5} }
)
```

The result should be Seattle at the top, but I am getting all records just like the command : `db.business.find()`.

Am I doing the right thing?

The result I would like is:

```
           "branch" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "Seattle",
                "location" : [ 
                    -122.326241, 
                    47.599146
                ],
                "_id" : ObjectId("5466f87edb96504c30e910dc")
            },
            {
                "name" : "Redmond",
                "location" : [ 
                    -122.130137,
                    47.644702
                ],
                "_id" : ObjectId("5466f87edb96504c30e910dd")
            }            ]
```

Answer (score 2):

maxDistance is given in meters, whereas the distance between the points is much bigger than 5m. If you values accordingly (I assume you meant miles), the query should work.

Furthermore, your places are stored within a single document. MongoDB won't sort arrays of an document according to the distance. If you had the locations in different documents, they'd be happily sorted by distance.

Comment: Result does not show Seattle to be the first.I have tried to make the maxDistance to 0.5m, the results are still the same, and is with Redmond.

Comment: @KevFixx: A query will always return a complete document. it will not be modified.

Comment: Thanks @Markus. Maybe my question is not clear, the result I wanted is sorted by location.

Comment: @KevFixx: Your question _is_ clear. But you have both locations in a _single_ document. MongoDB won't sort the array holding the locations.

Comment: Could you add that to your answer?